# Convert an existing http relay server currently deployed as a windows service to handle https requests

Tags: vb.net, sockets, iis, https, windows-services

I have a custom coded relay server application in VB.NET that is currently deployed as a windows service.

It accepts HTTP web requests from a client using a Tcp Listener, parses the requests and forwards it to another remotely hosted service via socket communication. The result from the service is then sent back by my relay server to the original client as a http response.

This functionality works perfectly as of now, but I would now like to upgrade my relay server to accept HTTPS requests instead of http.
I am not sure how to move ahead with this scenario.

I researched and found the following 2 options but I am not sure which is better and feasible?
One, I explicitly upgrade my current code to handle https handshake, certificate validation etc (if so, how?) or second option, can my current application be hosted on IIS to handle this scenario (if so, how)?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

A possible solution is to use IIS with Application Request Routing (ARR) as a reverse proxy in front of your service (its not possible to "Host" your service in IIS as such).

You could setup IIS/ARR with a certificate and suitable HTTPS binding, then configure ARR to proxy the HTTPS requests onto your service listening on HTTP. No changes required to your service's code.

Take a look at the following example:  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/extensions/url-rewrite-module/reverse-proxy-with-url-rewrite-v2-and-application-request-routing

In your case your service listening on port 80 is no different to a website running in IIS. The above example is more complicated than you need (as its reverse proxy'ing 2 websites based on a prefix of the URL), but it gives you a starting point.

A further possible step to force all traffic to use HTTPS would be to change the port your service uses (eg to 8080 instead of 80), then setup IIS to handle port 80 to perform a redirect to 443, and then use 443 and ARR to proxy your traffic to your service on 8080.2